# How do I use a variable from a different function in another function?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have one method

```
Public CurrentFileNameNoExtension As String
Public Sub importexcelfile()

CurrentFileNameNoExtension ="Filename"
'do something 

End Sub
```

I want to use **CurrentFileNameNoExtension** value in **onEnter** event of the dropdown list(**cmvalues**) event. That Value use in sql query. My code is

```
Private Sub cmvalues_Enter()
Dim qstng As String
qstng = CurrentFileNameNoExtension
Me.cmvalues.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Me.cmvalues.RowSource = "Select F1 from " & qstng & " WHERE F1 <> 'Control Model';"

End Sub
```

But **qstng** value is empty. it is not giving the value in the **importexcelfile()** function.

Comment: Kindly see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840414/excel-vba-use-an-existing-string-in-called-sub/21840638#21840638) answer for an alternative. Reason is, globals are kind of tricky to use, so passing in to another sub is also a viable idea. :)

Comment: what is the value of `CurrentFileNameNoExtension`? Are you sure it isn't empty when cmvalues_Enter is called? I.e. are you sure importexcelfile() has been called first?

Comment: Yes importexcelfile() called first from where i get **CurrentFileNameNoExtension** value. I checked it has filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this function under **Microsoft Access Class Objects** Form control,Where **cmvalues** dropdown exists

```
    Public CurrentFileNameNoExtension As String
    Public Sub importexcelfile()

    CurrentFileNameNoExtension ="Filename"
     'do something 

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As I've just noticed, thanks to @simoco, that this is indeed for a userform, there are actually a couple of things to pull this off. One is using globals, which is quite tricky, and another is to use a function to get the string you want.

```
Function CurrentFileNameNoExtension() As String
    'Do some FSO or GetOpenFileName here.
    CurrentFileNameNoExtension = "Filename"
End Sub

Private Sub cmvalues_Enter()
    qstng = CurrentFileNameNoExtension
    Me.cmvalues.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    Me.cmvalues.RowSource = "Select F1 from " & strFileName & " WHERE F1 <> 'Control Model';"
End Sub
```

There is not much of an issue using the code you have, really. You just have to make sure that the first sub is called before the second one so that `cmvalues_Enter` has a valid string to process.

Comment: It is throwing an exception says **Procedur declaration does not match or procedure having the samename** when form is loading.

Comment: @BK201, `cmvalues_Enter` is event - you can't add parametr to it:) But you can `Call importexcelfile` just before `qstng = CurrentFileNameNoExtension` in Op's code to initialize variable:)

Comment: Argggh! WTH. Long shift. This is indeed a USERFORM SUB! Editing.

Comment: i cannot call **importexcelfile ** method because it will open dialogue to select excel file., from where i get filename :)

Comment: Since you have a Catch-22 with the sequence of calls / dialogue, can you add a listbox that contains all of the allowed TABLE names, then have the user select one entry BEFORE going into the 'Enter' event?  Or ask the user BEFORE the 'Enter' event?

Comment: I cannot do that, the tablename changes every time when user selects the excel file(Converts the excel filename into tablename)

Comment: when i'm trying to select dropdown the drodown is opening dialogue, i don't want to open dialog